# Apache Ignite: How to get cached item without affinity key

Tags: c#, .net, ignite, gridgain

I have two caches, one is for Person and another is for Company objects, By specifying the Person.Id as the key and Person.CompanyId as the affinity key.

```
personCache.Put(new AffinityKey(p1.Id, p1.CompanyId), p1);
companyCache.Put(c1.Id, c1);
```

Is it possible to get the person from the cache using Person.Id? (without having Person.CompanyId)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not with Key-Value API.

Key-Value API, by definition, requires a key to access the data. If your key is `AffinityKey(personId, companyId)` then you have to construct the full key object in order to use the `IgniteCache::get` operation.

However, there is also SQL API which is another interface to access the same data. You can declare the cache as an SQL-enabled cache and the `personId` as an SQL field in that cache.

There are multiple ways to create an SQL-enabled cache:

- Create it with the `CREATE TABLE` statement (as opposed to specifying it in the node config or creating with the `createCache` method).
- Specify `indexedTypes` as a part of the `CacheConfiguration` and annotate the fields of the key and value objects as `@QuerySqlField`.
  The problem with `indexedTypes` is that you have to put annotations into classes. Obviously, this is not going to work with `AffinityKey` class, as you can't change it.
- Specify `QueryEntity` as a part of the `CacheConfiguration`.
  The problem with `QueryEntity` is that it may get pretty complex, and it's generally a bit harder to maintain then `@QuerySqlField` annotations.

In your case, I would recommend not to use `AffinityKey` class and create your own version of it - let's call it `PersonKey`. You can annotate its fields and use `indexedTypes`.

Below is a short example:

```java
public class SqlFieldInKeyExample {
    static class PersonKey {
        @QuerySqlField
        long personId;

        @QuerySqlField
        @AffinityKeyMapped
        long companyId;

        public PersonKey(long personId, long companyId) {
            this.personId = personId;
            this.companyId = companyId;
        }
    }

    static class Person {
        @QuerySqlField
        String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException {
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")) {
            CacheConfiguration<PersonKey, Person> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<PersonKey, Person>()
                .setName("PersonCache")
                .setIndexedTypes(PersonKey.class, Person.class);

            IgniteCache<PersonKey, Person> cache = ignite.createCache(cfg);

            cache.put(new PersonKey(9000, 42), new Person("John Doe"));

            List<List<?>> result = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE PERSONID = 9000")).getAll();
            assert result.size() == 1;
            System.out.println(">>>>> Person: " + result.get(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Output (among other things) is:

```
>>>>> Person: [9000, 42, John Doe]
```